# Trigger an SSRS report from a Process Dialog

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have several custom reports and I would like to be able to trigger them from a CRM Dialog.

Is it possible? And if so, any examples would be great!

Answer (score 3):

To actually *execute* the report (rather than display it) requires much more work. We have used a "trigger entity" model in the past.

In summary, your workflow or dialog you create an instance of the Report Trigger entity which has attributes holding the report to run (relative URL in SSRS) and the entity that should be passed as a parameter to the dataset. On create of such a trigger record, we have registered a plugin which invokes the SSRS web service, executes and then renders the report to PDF. Since there is no way merely display this report to the user you then have to decide whether the rendered report will be emailed to the calling user or, in our case, committed to a contextual SharePoint document library for the record that was processed in the original workflow.

Our requirements were very specific ;) Also, this won't work in CRM Online since there is no exposure of the SSRS Web Service.

In your case, given the interactive nature of a Process Dialog I think that James' approach is likely a better fit. I've added this as an intro to potentially another option. Happy to post more if it will fit your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to open the report with a url as shown [here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2006/01/27/15689.aspx).

Then you just present the url in the dialog.

[image]